# Delete multiple emails from email server (pop)

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have to delete emails that are older than six months and bigger than 1mb from multiple accounts, and my email webclient doesn't allow me to filter by those at the same time, so I'm looking for a way or tool to do it.

I tried adding the accounts to thunderbird (latest build), and use custom filters, but when I try to run the filter, thunderbird doesn't delete those emails from the server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Set up the account as IMAP then sort the emails by date and size.   You can then easily delete the messages that fit your criteria.

Comment: On thunderbird?

Comment: Yessir.  Below are links on how to setup Thunderbird on IMAP and sort by message size.  
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization  
and    
https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/NETADMINWIKI/Sorting+email+by+message+size,+Thunderbird (older link)

Comment: Agree, third party email client is the way to do what you want.

Comment: Didn´t work. I can short the emails in any way. The problem is that thunderbird only delete the emails from the local hd, but they still on the server.

Comment: Check your settings per http://kb.mozillazine.org/Deleting_messages_in_IMAP_accounts